# fadeOut(...).removeClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am having a little problem when I am building a slider with images. I am a beginner in javascript and jquery so I've built id based on what I've done on codeacademy a while back (used to work fine there but it doesn't work anymore even there). It works fine when I click the next arrow but when I click the previous arrow it doesn't work anymore. It says in console "Uncaught TypeError: currentSlide.fadeOut(...).removeCLass is not a function".

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide slide1 active-slide">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide2">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide3">
    </div>
    <div class="slide slide4">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider-nav">
    <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="images/props/arrow-prev.png"></a>
    <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="images/props/arrow-next.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:550px;
}
.slide{
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
.slide1{
    background-image:url('images/main/slider/1.jpg');
    height:100%
}
.slide2{
    background-image:url('images/main/slider/2.jpg');
    height:100%
}
.slide3{
    background-image:url('images/main/slider/3.jpg');
    height:100%
}
.slide4{
    background-image:url('images/main/slider/4.jpg');
    height:100%
}
.active-slide{
    display:block;
}
```

And finally JAVASCRIPT:

```
var main = function(){

    $('.arrow-next').click(function(){
       var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
       var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

       if (nextSlide.length == 0){
        nextSlide = $('.slide').first();   
       }

       currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
       nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

       currentDot = $('.active-dot');
       nextDot = currentDot.next();

       if (nextDot.length == 0){
        nextDot = $('.dot').first();   
       }

       currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
       nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });

    $('.arrow-prev').click(function(){
       var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
       var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

       if (prevSlide.length == 0){
        prevSlide = $('.slide').last();   
       }

       currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeCLass('active-slide');
       prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

       currentDot = $('.active-dot');
       prevDot = currentDot.prev();

       if (prevDot.lenth == 0){
        prevDot = $('.dot').last();
       }

       currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
       prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first I see is that you called removeCLass. Capital letter "L"

Maybe this was your fault.

Or maybe a wrong jquery version.

When I simply try

```
$("body").fadeOut(600).addClass("hello")
```

it works correctly

Comment: Oh wow, I tried looking at the code for like 45 minutes and I haven't found this simple solution. Thanks a lot, you saved me. Tried it now and it works. Just wondering, I am new to stackoverflow; can I add a little side question here?

Comment: You can add more to this topic here as a new answer. If you have a complete other solution then open a new question.